# PHP Mysql fetched data blank

Tags: php, mysql

Having a bit of an issue with my php code..

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TheGroup = :SearchName ORDER BY TheTime DESC");
$stmt->bindParam(':SearchName', $request, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$count = count($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $mTheAvatar = $result[$i]->TheAvatar;
    $mTheDirection= $result[$i]->TheDirection;
    $mTheGroup = $result[$i]->TheGroup;
    $mTheMedia = $result[$i]->TheMedia;
    $mTheMessage = $result[$i]->TheMessage;
    $mTheSenderName= $result[$i]->TheSenderName;
    $mTheThumbImage = $result[$i]->TheThumbImage;
    $mTheTime = $result[$i]->TheTime;
    $mTheMediaExtension = $result[$i]->TheMediaExtension;

    echo "hello";
    echo $mTheAvatar;
    echo "    <- this is avatar";
}
```

If I do a Var_dump() I see the data being requested without a problem.
If I echo the variables , they are blank..
I have triple checked that the table column names are correct..

the $mTheAvater is a pic in table, if that gives a possible clue, but the rest are blank as well so not sure what is up?!?

Comment: Could you include the output of `var_dump()` here?

Answer (score 3):

You can test:

```
$mTheAvatar = $result[$i]['TheAvatar'];
```

As I know in the `FETCH_ASSOC` it returns data in above structure.

Comment: That's right, `FETCH_ASSOC` returns an associative array

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read them as if they are objects, but [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array, so your code should look like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $mTheAvatar = $result[$i]['TheAvatar'];
    $mTheDirection= $result[$i]['TheDirection'];
    .
    .
    .
    .
    echo "hello";
    echo $mTheAvatar;
    echo "    <- this is avatar";
}
```

If you want to handle objects, you should use [`PDOStatement::fetchObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)

Comment: Thanks, it was def the [' ... '] I was missing

Answer (score 0):

This should be better - 1) it's using foreach; 2) unset(); 3) different structure

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE TheGroup = :SearchName ORDER BY TheTime DESC");
$stmt->bindParam(':SearchName', $request, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($results){

  foreach($results as $result_data) {

    echo $result_data['TheAvatar'];

    echo $result_data['TheDirection'];

     //and so on

    unset($result_data);

  }

}
else{

    echo 'Empty';

}
```